# Escaping variables in bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init

I'm creating a init.d script within a bash file, which goes as follows:

```
# AUTOSTART
$APPDIR=somedir
$APPCONF=somedir
$APPVENV=somedir
$APPUSER=someuser
cat <<EOF >/etc/init.d/uwsgi
#!/bin/bash
daemon=$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi
args="--emperor $APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini --daemonize /var/log/emperor.log --emperor-pidfile $APPDIR/emperor.pid --gid `id -g $APPUSER`"
pid=$APPDIR/emperor.pid
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon -m -p $pid --start --exec $daemon $args
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping script uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon --signal INT -p $pid --stop $daemon $args
        ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading conf"
        kill -HUP $(cat $pid)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
EOF
```

It is my understanding, from help, that $APPCONF, $APPVENV, $APPUSER and $APPDIR need to be escaped because I define them outside the file. So is it correct that I simply put a back slash in front of the variable like this:

```
daemon=\$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi
args="--emperor \$APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini --daemonize /var/log/emperor.log --emperor-pidfile \$APPDIR/emperor.pid --gid `id -g \$APPUSER`"
pid=\$APPDIR/emperor.pid
```

It still doesn't seem to work though, the service doesn't start, so I think I might have done something else wrong. Can anyone confirm I am escaping properly please?

Comment: You don't assign variable names by using `$` in front of them in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar sign is only used for reading/using the value of a variable, not when setting its value. Thus, setting `APPDIR` to `somedir` would look like this:

```
APPDIR=somedir
```

Depending on how you call the script, you may also want to export the variable:

```
export APPDIR=somedir
```

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. What about the rest of my escaping though, is that correct?

Comment: Just from looking at it, I don't see anything else that should cause problems.

Comment: Only escape the `$` if you *want* a literal dollar sign to appear in `/etc/init.d/uwsgi`, rather than the value of `$APPDIR`, etc. I suspect you do not want to escape the `$`, though, since you give values to the variables prior to writing the file.

Comment: You *do* want to escape the `$` for `$daemon`, `$pid`, and `$args`, though, since those are values set inside the script you are writing to disk.

Comment: @chepner is right. I got the question slightly wrong there.